# Aliasing associations in Rails 7.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

In olden times, I could do this:

```
class Thing < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :thing_member

  alias_attribute :member, :thing_member
end

Thing.new(thing_member: blah) => success!
Thing.new(member: blah) => also success!
```

With Rails 7.1 we now get a deprecation warning saying `.member` isn't a true attribute and we should stop using `alias_attribute` and use `alias_method` instead. Fair enough, but following that advice breaks stuff:

```
class Thing < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :thing_member

  alias_method :member, :thing_member
end

Thing.new(thing_member: blah) => success!
Thing.new(member: blah) => NoMethodError: undefined method `member='
```

Defining the association twice works, but feels icky:

```
class Thing < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :thing_member
  belongs_to :member, class_name: "ThingMember", foreign_key: "thing_member_id"
end

Thing.new(thing_member: blah) => success!
Thing.new(member: blah) => Pyrrhic victory :(
```

Is there a better, canonical way of achieving this? Is this just a Bad Practice to avoid? Could and should there be an `alias_association` macro for this situation?

Comment: I think defining the association twice is actually the best option as the macro defines a lot of methods that you need to alias and it created two entries in the association metadata so it actually behaves like an associtions. I would however work towards deprechiating the one you don't actually need.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Shopify, a huge user and contributor to rails, has an open PR for adding an `alias_association` feature...

I think this has a good chance of being included in Rails 7.2 when it is released.

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/49801

---

Rather than say 'you should not use or do that', let me illustrate the benefit of this.

Say you've got a Person, with one or more addresses and each address has one or more deliveries:

```rb
class Person
  has_many :person_addresses
  alias_association :addresses, :person_addresses
end
class PersonAddress
  belongs_to :person
  has_many :address_deliveries
  alias_association :deliveries, :address_deliveries
end
class AddressDelivery
  belongs_to :person_address
end

# Without aliases
deliveries = person.person_addresses.collect(&:address_deliveries).flatten

# With aliases
person.addresses.collect(&:deliveries).flatten
```

There's value in naming the tables this way so it's obvious what table relationships exist and they line up next to each other.

But I also like aliasing those relationships for more 'terse' and human-like code when accessing those relationships as the caller.

And I have done this a lot in an existing Rails application and don't want to have to change a bunch of entries to define the relationships twice which defeats the purpose of the alias.

I suspect Shopify uses this simplication a lot and thus they opened the PR.

Comment: This is precisely the use case I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably just add my own `alias_association` that did both the getter and setter. Stick it up in `ApplicationRecord` for fun and profit.

Comment: Associations are a lot more than just a setter and getter though.

Comment: I mean OP was happy with what `alias_attribute` was providing previously, so that's what I focused on, but sure - if they want more than that then they should add that to their implementation of `alias_association`.

Comment: Getting downvoted when Shopify themselves opened a PR for this very behavior... it IS more complicated, but if you see my answer, I think it's a worthy feature.